# Right-aligned labels in WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, label

The most obvious way to right-align a `Label` in WinForms doesn't work: setting anchor to Top/Bottom Right and TextAlign to TopRight. If the text changes the label's Left coordinate remains unchanged instead of the Right coordinate (which, one might argue, is a bug).

For this reason I've always used a full-width `TableLayoutPanel` for right-aligned labels. However this is not always very convenient, depending on the layout in question...

So, I wonder if there are any other ways to keep a Label right-aligned in WinForms that never occurred to me?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

One simple option is to disable `AutoSize` (set to `false`) and over-size it so there is spare space.

Alternatively, perhaps use `Dock` instead of just `Anchor`, although this has a different meaning, so you may need to put it in a `Panel` or similar). Ultimately this works like the first - by over-sizing it in the first place; so perhaps the first option is simpler.

Comment: Ah, yes, these can also be used depending on circumstances. I'm always a little worried that on other systems the text may not fit vertically since the first method disables vertical autosizing. Any comments regarding whether this is ever a problem?

Comment: No huge thoughts; of course, WPF may have more flexibility ;-p

Comment: AutoSize...blerg...you don't write Windows applications for a couple years and you forget all these nuances.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Using a TableLayoutPanel with docked labels is the only reliable method that I've found for placing right-aligned labels in Winforms.  Turning off AutoSize and using oversized labels seems to cause strange anomalies for High DPI users.

Comment: I tried the TableLaoutPanel, it's shame to correctly align one label but if works then great. However the text kept wrapping onto the next line for me any advice?

Answer (score 9):

Using a FlowLayoutPanel to do it works very well.

```
flowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label);
```

Then, just make sure that the flowLayoutPanel is large enough for the label to expand.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what worked for me on a standard form

- Set AutoSize property off for just the Labels to be right aligned
- Make all the fields the same size (perhaps this isn't really required) using the Layout toolbar
- Multi-select the labels and right align them using the Layout toolbar, position where desired
- Set TextAlign property to one of the xxxRight settings, e.g, TopRight

Answer (score 2):

Well as [Sphax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087602/sphax) noticed you have to:

1. Set `AutoSize` to false
2. Set `TextAlign` to Right, for example to `MiddleRight`
3. Resize label to real size using `MeasureString`

Code:

```
label.AutoSize = false; 
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;    

int yourWidthHere = 100;    
using (Graphics g = label.CreateGraphics())    
{    
     SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, label.Font, yourWidthHere);    
     label.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(size.Height);    
     label.Text = text;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- dynamically created label's  default autosize is false.
- if label's autosize is false. it contains extra empty space.
- that tricks you to think its doesnt right align properly. to diagnose it,
  set the label's backColour to lightgreen

[image]

```
 int rowIndex=1;

 var lbx = new Label();
 lbx.AutoSize = true;          // default is false.
 lbx.BackColor = Color.Green;  // to see if it's aligning or not
 lbx.Text = "Iam  Autosize=true";
 lbx.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
 tlPanel.Controls.Add(lbx, 0, rowIndex);

 var dtp = new DateTimePicker();
 dtp.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
 tlPanel.Controls.Add(dtp, 1, rowIndex);


  //--- row 2  autosize false
 rowIndex=2;
  var lbx2 = new Label();
 lbx2.AutoSize = false;          // default is false.
 lbx2.BackColor = Color.Green;  // to see if it's aligning or not
 lbx2.Text = "AutoSz=false";
 lbx2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
 tlPanel.Controls.Add(lbx2, 0, rowIndex);

 var dtp = new DateTimePicker();
 dtp.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
 tlPanel.Controls.Add(dtp, 1, rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that hasn't been mentioned yet.

I worked around a similar issue by not using a Label at all. Instead, you can use a TextBox.

On the TextBox, set the following properties:

```
BorderStyle = None
BackColor = the color of your form
TextAlign = Right
```

To suppress any visible cursor or user interaction, add a handler for the Enter event. In there, find another control (could be a hidden label), and call Focus on that:

```
private void txtFakeLabel_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblHidden.Focus();
}
```

This responds very nicely to changing the 'label' text dynamically, as long as you make the control wide enough for the text that will appear there.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a control progrmatically, I found it helped to **give it a starting location** near the location you're trying to anchor it to.

The code below anchors a label to the bottom right of the parent control. It was anchoring to the *top left* until I added the `lblPagename.Location` line specifying a location currently near the bottom right. Now when I resize, it stays anchored toward the bottom right (maintaining the padding set below).

```
int intLabelWidth = 250;
int intLabelHeight = 20;
int intPadding = 20;

Label lblPagename = new Label();
lblPagename.Name = "lblPageName";
lblPagename.Text = "Page Name";
lblPagename.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8F, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
lblPagename.AutoSize = false;
lblPagename.Size = new Size(intLabelWidth, intLabelHeight);
lblPagename.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
lblPagename.Location = new Point(ctl.Width - intLabelWidth - intPadding, ctl.Height - intLabelHeight - (intPadding * 2));
lblPagename.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);
prnt.Controls.Add(lblPagename);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you set the form property RightToLeft = yes; 
so you should not use the Text Align property just set the Anchor.
try this approaches:

```
Form.righttoleft = yes;
label.anchor = Top, Right;
label.TextAlign = TopLeft;
```

or

```
Form.righttoleft = No;
label.anchor = Top, Right;
label.TextAlign = TopRight;
```

or

```
Form.righttoleft = yes;
label.righttoleft = No;
label.anchor = Top, Right;
label.TextAlign = TopRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was:

1. Set the AutoSize property labels to false. Set the TextAlign
2. property labels to something on the right.
3. Resize manually the
   labels 1 by 1 so they can use more space.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to the labels' SizeChanged event:

```
private void label1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Location = new Point(Your_Anchor_Point - label1.Width, label1.Location.Y);
}
```

To be more DPI friendly consider using some other control as the anchor point, i.e.

```
label1.Location = new Point(dataGridView1.Location.X + dataGridView1.Width - label1.Width, label1.Location.Y);
```

to align to the RH side of the dgv.

(BTW: I tried the Paint & TextChanged events but they seemed to sometimes get confused - probably something to do with event order particularly on opening a new form.)